# row = result.fetchone() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

Tags: sql, postgresql, flask-restful

I have a python script that is supposed to 'GET' information from a postgres database

create_table.py

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource

import psycopg2

class single_user_Request(Resource):
   def get(self, username):
      connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'tracker' "
                                  "user = 'postgres' "
                                  "password='rasengan1408' "
                                  "host = 'localhost' "
                                  "port='5432'")
      cursor = connection.cursor()

      query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s"
      result = cursor.execute(query, (username,))
      row = result.fetchone()
      connection.close()
      if row:
          return {'req_id':row[0], 'username':row[1], 'equipment_name': row[2], 'requesttype':row[3], 'description': row[4], 'status':row[5]}
      return {'message':'request not found'}, 404
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from app.api.v1.requests import single_user_Request


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = 'GciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOj'
    api = Api(app)


    api.add_resource(single_user_Request, '/api/v1/userrequests/<string:username>')

return app
```

run.py

```
from app.api import create_app

app = create_app()

app.run(debug=True)
```

After running the script

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

I'm struggling to see why fetchone would be a nonetype object if the database has data

Answer (score 4):

`cursor.execute` doesn't return anything,
you need to change you code like this

```
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s"
cursor.execute(query, (username,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the code in the screenshot below worked perfectly on my machine (laptop).

[image]

But when I tried to access the same route (all_predictions) on another machine, the application crashed with an error message that says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

After wasting half a day, I realized in my case, the error was a result of the SqlAlchemy version.

The version I had on my laptop was

```
SQLAlchemy==1.3.8
```

And the version on the new machine was

```
SQLAlchemy==1.4.35
```

So I uninstalled the above version by running:

```
pip uninstall SQLAlchemy
```

and then installed the specific 1.3.8 version by running:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy==1.3.8
```

Boom! the error disappeared, and everything worked fine.